# Typescript check React children for specific component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a component that takes children:

```
interface FooProps {
  title: string;
}

const Foo: React.FC<FooProps> = ({ children, title }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

Now I want to restrict `children` to only accept a specific component - let's say a `Button` component. Is there a way to define this in `FooProps`?

A common method seems to be:

```
interface FooProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<Button>;
  title: string;
}
```

However this only checks that ANY element is passed as long as the children props are correct. My `Button` component may not have any required props, so this this technique would end up essentially allowing any children types. Is there a stronger way to type this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without using a discriminant property. `interface ButtonProps { brand: 'exclusiveButton' }`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković yeah I thought that might be the case